# Python files not executed by command prompt

Tags: python

So I dont know what happened but my python files are not being executed by the command prompt.

```
C:/Users/MOHAMMED/Local/Programs/Python/Python39>button.py
```

Above is what im trying to do. but it keeps giving me errors.

```
This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action.
```

I have been using cmd prompt everyday to execute python files but today it is not working. any help is appreciated.

(I use IDLE to do my code btw)

edit:
So this is what i do when im trying to execute files using cmd prompt.

1. I go into the directory of where all the python files are stored by using `cd` command.
   2)then i just say the name of the file and it works.

but today i installed pip by using setup program and after pip was installed, i cant execute python file using cmd prompt.

Comment: try running the python setup again and choose "repair"

Comment: did it. not working.

Comment: have you tried follwing the steps from Jaysmito Mukherjee's answer to add python to environment variables?

Comment: i did that too.

Comment: note that you have to restart your CMD for the changes to take effect (open a new prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute the wrong way it should be:

```
python button.py
```

If that doesn't work then :

The complete path of python.exe can be added by:

Right-clicking This PC and going to Properties.

Clicking on the Advanced system settings in the menu on the left.

Clicking on the Environment Variables button o​n the bottom right.

In the System variables section, selecting the Path variable and clicking on Edit. The next screen will show all the directories that are currently a part of the PATH variable.

Clicking on New and entering Python’s install directory.

Then again try :

```
python button.py
```

Comment: It cannot be can you please give a screenshot?

Comment: sorry i didnt see a part of your comment.